# Sharing network automatically disabled the shared network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, network-shares, hotspot

When I share a network to other users in my network the way described [here](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot), the shared network instantly disabled and it says "unidentified network", when I turn off the sharing option, my original Internet connection also functioning.

Comment: Can you try *all* the steps in [this](http://winsupersite.com/article/faqtip/windows-7-tip-of-the-week-use-wireless-hosted-networking-to-share-an-internet-connection-wirelessly). It uses Windows' `hostednetwork` command-line feature. The guide also tells you how to make sure your adaptor is configured properly

Comment: @czupe: what do you mean by the network being disabled? Do you mean inactive, disconnected or actually disabled (grayed out in control panel)?

Comment: thank you guys for your comment maybe i should attach a screenshot here, to be more clear.

Comment: @shub: i've seen already your linked site, and tried with hostednetwork command-line feature with first time. Anyway do not know how, but restart do the work, now i can share my network. Really weird.